# Changing background image css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this simple code trying to change background image of a div. It doesn't work.

```
<div id="lyt_photo_1" style="position:absolute; top:19mm; left:4mm; background-color:#999999; width:21mm; height:27mm;"></div>
<script>$('#lyt_photo_1').css("background-image", "url(/Jellyfish.jpg)");</script>
```

Comment: you have to give more information. In principle, the code has no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vaz8r7m3/)
  It works , That means your image directory path (`/Jellyfish.jpg`) is wrong

```
<div id="lyt_photo_1" style="position:absolute; top:19mm;
 left:4mm;  width:21mm; height:27mm;"></div>

$('#lyt_photo_1').css("background-image", "url(http://lh4.ggpht.com/_X6JnoL0U4BY/S-AGp
sMhh4I/AAAAAAAAc2I/PhQJvcAMLgI
/tmp18723_thumb_thumb_thumb.jpg?imgmax=800)");
```

Answer (score 0):

// store the image link inside a variable from 'src' attribute
var getImageSrc = $('.yourclassname img').attr('src');

// add div background image using the variable above
$('.lyt_photo_1').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');